# Textfile into singly linked list, user searches for word, C++

Tags: c++, time, full-text-search, user-input, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to read a large textfile into a singly linked list, separate out each word (using a space as a delimiter) and then have a user find any word that may be in the textfile. I'm also trying to time how long it takes the search. I'm able to start the program fine, with the console prompting the user for input but after I enter my word to search for, the program stops working. Any idea what might be causing the error?

Here's the main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include "List.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    List myList;
    string s;
    string line;
    ifstream ifs("pg1250.txt");

    if(ifs.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(ifs, line, ' '))
        {
            myList.add(line);
        }
        ifs.close();
    }
    string key;
    cout<<"Please enter a word to find"<<endl;
    cin>>key;
    myList.find(key);
    return 0;
}
```

And the List class

```
#include "List.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

List::List(){
}
void List::add(string s){
    if(cursor==NULL)
    {
        start->data=s;
        cursor = start;
        end = start;
    }
    else
    {
        end = new Node(s);
        cursor->next = end;
        cursor = end;
    }

}
void List::read(List l){
    string line;
    ifstream ifs("pg1250.txt");

    if(ifs.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(ifs, line, ' '))
        {
            l.add(line);
        }
        ifs.close();
    }
}
void List::find(string key)
    {
        cursor = start;
        int position = 1;
        while(cursor->data!=key)
        {
            cursor = cursor->next;
            position++;
                    if(cursor==end)
                    break;


        if(cursor->data==key)
        {
            cout<<"Found at " << position << endl;
        }

        else
        {
            cout<<"Not found!" <<endl;
        }
}
#include <fstream>
#include "Node.h"
using namespace std;
class List{
public:
List();
void add(string);
void find(string);
void read(List);
Node* cursor;
Node* start;
Node* end;
};
```

And node class/h.

```
#include "Node.h"


Node::Node()
{
    data = "";
    next = NULL;
}

Node::Node(string s)
{
    data = s;
    next = NULL;
}
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Node

{public:
    Node(void);
    Node(string);
    string data;
    Node* next;
};
```

I know using namespace in a header file is looked down upon. Any idea what may be causing the problem? I got a friend of mine to look at the List find() method and nothing stuck out as odd. Thanks for any insight!

Comment: why dont you try to solve the problem with `stl list`

Comment: Part of the exercise is creating my own linked list.

Comment: If your purpose is to read whitespace separated strings, just use the `std::string` extraction operator for `std::istream`. `while (ifs >> str) { do something with str }`

Answer (score 0):

```
List::List(){
     start = NULL;
     cursor = NULL;
}
```

You haven't initialized these variable. Default value of class variables are not NULL and in `add()` method you are checking `if(cursor==NULL)`. This might be the problem.

Comment: thanks for catching that. I have fixed the issue. I don't think I'm using the ifstream right because when I try a test cout after the if, whatever's inside the condition doesn't print and it skips straight out of the loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure check whether text is present in the file. Same code is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not only are you forgetting to intialize start and cursor (like HadeS said), but you also try to dereference start before constructing a node (line 10 of List.cpp), which should lead to a segfault.